# email client with snooze functionality

Tags: productivity, email-client, thunderbird

I'm using Thunderbird as my main mail client for years. I also use the mailmindr plugin which allows to snooze mails, but the plugin seems to not be under active development and isnt compatible to current thunderbird versions. The main problem I have is that it sometimes mixes up mails with the wrong subject which is a no-go.

This snooze functionality is such a big productivity boost for me that I don't want to miss it anymore.

So I am searching for an email client with these functions:

- multiple accounts and multiple identities per account
- preferably open source
- snooze mails: hide selected mail(s) until a given time, the delay can be set as hours/days from now or maybe input/selected as a date/time string. When that time has come, the mails shows up again in my inbox.
- IMAP/SMTP support
- good GPG support
- must run on my Linux desktop

I already considered moving to mutt/neomutt, but I couldn't find out if they have such a functionality or if I can easily add it via some scripting.

Comment: Is the existing plugin FOSS?

Comment: I'm not sure: https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/mailmindr/
It is released under the Mozilla Public License and the addon's homepage isnt existing anymore. So I couldnt find the source code.

Comment: If you look on The Wayback machine at archive.org you can find the page, download the code and fork it, if you want to.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I didnt find the code there, but there is a GitHub copy of it here: https://github.com/hullin/mailmindr
But I am still interested if this workflow can also be achieved with other clients, e.g. mutt.

Comment: I have been looking for the same thing for some time.  mailspring looks like a possibility but I wasn't able to build it from source and I don't have root on the machine I want to run it on.  Pretty surprising gap here.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like updates to mailmindr are now being posted to the official website.

See here: https://twitter.com/mailmindr/status/1122932917334892545

And here: https://mailmindr.net/en/download.html